# Can't seem to get php to display an inverted exclamation point from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

The title is self-explanatory. I have tried adding:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');
```

to the beginning of the file. Without that it displays fine on a browser but a distorted character in a shell. With it added it removes the inverted exclamation point under both a browser and a shell. Entering the same query right into the MySQL shell works fine, so the shell is capable of displaying the character, and properly. Ultimately, I want to ignore this character from the beginning of a title for sorting purposes (¡Three Amigos!).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the mysql_set_charset function.